# Android Release APK crash immediately on launch - React Native ( Version 0.58.4)

Tags: android, react-native, windows-10

I have an issue with react native (ver 0.59.4) release APK.
    The app runs well on debug mode but it crashes immediately on release mode, Got these message from the logcat which is probably causing this problem

```
2019-05-30 09:45:38.632 1150-1263/? E/View: focusableViewAvailable: current thread is android.anim, return!
2019-05-30 09:45:38.649 2852-6156/? E/[HwRecSys]HwRecSysService: getIsRportDirectService is false!
2019-05-30 09:45:38.717 1150-7764/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
2019-05-30 09:45:38.728 2852-6156/? E/[HwRecSys]HwRecSysService: getIsRportDirectService is false!
2019-05-30 09:45:38.852 1771-13995/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103.
```

**Assemble Release log as below:**

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :react-native-navigation
>   downloadRobolectricDependencies D:\svn\Inspection-Tool\code\MobileApp\trunk\InspectionTool\android\build/robolectric-dependencies
>
> Task :react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> Task :react-native-navigation:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>   Loading dependency graph, done.
>   info Writing bundle output to:, D:\svn\Inspection-Tool\code\MobileApp\trunk\InspectionTool\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle
>   info Done writing bundle output

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 36s
179 actionable tasks: 166 executed, 13 up-to-date

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "basicApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.3.4",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^1.1.7",
    "@valdio/react-native-scrollable-tabview": "^0.8.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native": "0.59.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-collapsible-list": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.493",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jestSetup/jestSetupFile.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

**-- Edited log ---**

```
2019-05-30 11:53:15.525 1150-1263/? E/View: focusableViewAvailable: current thread is android.anim, return!
2019-05-30 11:53:15.525 1150-1263/? E/View: focusableViewAvailable: current thread is android.anim, return!
2019-05-30 11:53:15.555 2852-6156/? E/[HwRecSys]HwRecSysService: getIsRportDirectService is false!
2019-05-30 11:53:15.603 1150-7764/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
2019-05-30 11:53:15.678 2852-6156/? E/[HwRecSys]HwRecSysService: getIsRportDirectService is false!
2019-05-30 11:53:15.755 1150-6006/? E/RMS.HwSysResManagerService: Process Permission error! pid:1810 uid:1001 Process.myPid:1150
2019-05-30 11:53:15.777 1150-2110/? E/RMS.HwSysResManagerService: Process Permission error! pid:1810 uid:1001 Process.myPid:1150
2019-05-30 11:53:15.782 1771-8437/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103
2019-05-30 11:53:15.842 1150-1263/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{9633689 u0 Splash Screen com.wtitool EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
2019-05-30 11:53:16.321 1150-1726/? E/HwReportTool: This is not beta user build
2019-05-30 11:53:16.326 1150-1726/? E/HwReportTool: This is not beta user build
2019-05-30 11:53:16.461 1150-1263/? E/View: focusableViewAvailable: current thread is android.anim, return!
2019-05-30 11:53:16.461 1150-1263/? E/View: focusableViewAvailable: current thread is android.anim, return!
2019-05-30 11:53:16.478 2852-6156/? E/[HwRecSys]HwRecSysService: getIsRportDirectService is false!
2019-05-30 11:53:16.556 1150-7764/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
2019-05-30 11:53:16.627 2852-6156/? E/[HwRecSys]HwRecSysService: getIsRportDirectService is false!
2019-05-30 11:53:16.733 1771-8437/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103
2019-05-30 11:53:16.746 1150-1263/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{fec2552 u0 Splash Screen com.wtitool EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
2019-05-30 11:53:17.045 14478-21090/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2019-05-30 11:53:17.063 14478-14556/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.api.feedcache.resync.NewsFeedCacheInvalidationGCMService{u=0 tag="NewsFeedCacheInvalidationGCMService" trigger=window{start=43200s,end=43230s,earliest=-44033370s,latest=-44033340s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-44076570s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-11020000}
2019-05-30 11:53:17.250 14478-14556/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable for task: com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.api.feedcache.resync.NewsFeedCacheInvalidationGCMService{u=0 tag="NewsFeedCacheInvalidationGCMService" trigger=window{start=43200s,end=43230s,earliest=-44033370s,latest=-44033340s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] attributes=[PERSISTED] scheduled=-44076570s last_run=N/A jid=N/A status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-11020000}
2019-05-30 11:53:17.276 1150-1726/? E/HwReportTool: This is not beta user build
2019-05-30 11:53:17.281 1150-1726/? E/HwReportTool: This is not beta user build
```

**Edited on 26/06/2019**

The issue was solved when I change my entry point in the file 'android/app/build.gradle' from

```
project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js"
]
to
project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.android.js"
]
```

Comment: There's nothing in the tiny snippet of log, you missed the stack trace

Comment: that is the wrong part of log.

Comment: Check the asset folder.  See if the index.android.bundle file is present in the release apk.

Comment: can you please again look into the edited logs

Comment: index.android.bundle file present under android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release